# Regex in Scala to extract value from a column

Tags: regex, scala

I have a column `content` that has below data

```
<div class="a-row">
<div class="a-column a-span10">
<div class="a-column a-mm">
</div>
<span class="a-">$20 </span>
</div> </div>
Get FREE baskets $15.01 items.
```

I need to extract 15.01 in scala which changes for every request.

I wrote the below code, I am not getting error, but the value is not getting captured

```
.withColumn("AB", regexp_extract($"content","Get\\s\\w*([0-9]\\d*)+.{3}",0))
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You are not matching the word "baskets", just a single "word" with `\w*` Try using `"\\bGet\\s\\D*(\\d+\\.(?:\\d+)?)\\b"`

Comment: I am getting the whole of "Get FREE baskets $15.01 items", is there a way just to get 15.01

Comment: I could pull it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either match `GET`  and then match until the first occurrence of a digit:

```
\bGet\s\D*(\d+\.(?:\d+)?)\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bGet\s` Match the word `Get` and a whitespace char
- `\D*` Match optional non digits
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+\.(?:\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

With the doubled backslashes:

```
"\\bGet\\s\\D*(\\d+\\.(?:\\d+)?)\\b"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qrymp4/1)

Or you can also prevent crossing `<` and `>` as well:

```
\bGet\s[^\d<>]*(\d+\.(?:\d+)?)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o81iZz/1)